# my if-statement is not doing what it want it to

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i really need help with a memory-style game that i have to create for a school project. The issue right now is that my if statements wont really work properly. i want to compare cards and then if they match they should stay open and the score should go up, and if they don't match they should close again. but right now it says the first card click is right and anything clicked on after that is wrong

```js
//Function for the dropdown content
function dropdownTips() {
    document.getElementById("mydropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}


window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowncontent");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
             if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
             openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
});

var score = 0;
var firstClick = null;
var secondoClick = null;
const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        cards[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
            cards[i].classList.add("open");
        })};

let clicked = event.target.dataset.type;
  
if(firstClick == null){
  firstClick = clicked
} else {
  secondoClick = clicked
}

  
if(secondoClick == firstClick){
  console.log('same click')
  score++;
  firstClick = null;
  secondoClick = null;
} else if(secondoClick != null && firstClick != secondoClick) {
  console.log('metti null')
  firstClick = null;
  secondoClick = null;
}});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color:#00005e;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17%;
  left: 39%;
  right: 40%;
  width: 355px;
}

/*The 'tips?' button and the drop down content*/
header button {
display: inline-flex;
position:absolute;
align-items: center;
right: 2%;
top: 15%;
bottom: 15%;
padding: 10px 20px;
font-size: 20px;
background-color:white;
color: #00005e;
border-radius: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
border-color: transparent;
}

header button:hover {
opacity: 80%;
}


.dropdowncontent {
display: none;
position: absolute;
right: 0%;
top: 100%;
background-color:#00005e;
min-width: 160px;
max-width: 400px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
z-index: 100;

}

.dropdowncontent li {
color: white;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.advise{
font-size: 19px;
}

.passwordtips {
font-size: 30px;
left: 20%;
}

.show {
display:block;
}

/*The link in the dropdowncontent*/
a {
text-decoration: underline;
color: white;
}

a:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

/*The score counter*/
.score {
  color: #01016e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

/*The game section*/
section {
  max-width: 1300px;
  height: 550px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-color: #00005e;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

/*The sections content*/
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 185px;
margin-top: 7px;
}

.card{
background-color: #01016e;
color: white;
margin: 10px 10px;
height: 150px;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 0;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.card h2{
  padding: 2px;
  transform: scale(-1,1);
}

.card:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.open{
animation: flip .5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes flip {
from { 
  background: #00005e;
  font-size: 0;
}
to{
  background: rgb(20, 73, 185);
  font-size:17px;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
}

/* .welcome {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
color: #3c3b6e;
margin-top: 100px;
font-size: 50px;
clear: both;
position: absolute;
}

.startbutton {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-self: center;
margin-top: 100px;
position: absolute;
background-color: #00005e;
color: #e8ebf1;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 30px;
border-radius: 4px;
z-index: 0;
border-color: transparent;
}

.startbutton:hover{
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #3c3b6e;
}
*/

/*The game*/


/*The 'DID YOU KNOW' over the ticker*/
.facts {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
margin-top: 30px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #00005e;
}

/*The facts ticker*/
.tcontainer {
max-width: 1200px;
margin-top: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1000;
}

.ticker-wrap {
width: 100%;
padding-left: 100%; 
background-color: #00005e;
}

@keyframes ticker {
0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
100% { transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
}
.ticker-move {
 display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
padding-right: 100%;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: ticker;
animation-duration: 55s;
}
.ticker-move:hover{
animation-play-state: paused; 
}

.ticker-item{
display: inline-block; 
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
padding-right: 3em;
color: white;
min-height: 40px;
font-size: 25px;
}


/*The pause button for the ticker*/
.pause {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.pausebutton {
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: #00005e;
color: white;
border-style: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.pausebutton:hover {
background-color: #3c3b6e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>The Password Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>THE PASSWORD GAME</h1>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropdownTips()" class="dropbtn">TIPS?</button>
            <div class="dropdowncontent" id="mydropdown" >
                <ul>
                    <li class="passwordtips">Tips for making strong passwords: </li>
                    <li class="advise">1. Use 16 characters or more (use both uppercase and lowercase letters, number and symbols.)</li>
                    <li class="advise">2. Never use the same password twice.</li>
                    <li class="advise">3. Use a password manager.</li>
                    <li class="advise">4. Don't write your passwords down on paper.</li>
                    <li class="advise">5. Don't share your passwords with others.</li>
                    <li class="advise">6. Change your password after a breach.</li>
                    <li class="advise">7. Sign up for data breach notifications. (like <a href="https://haveibeenpwned.com/" target="_blank">haveibeenpwned.com</a>).</li>
                    <li class="advise">8. Check your accounts regularly for any suspicious activity. </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="score"><h2></h2></div>

    <section>
        <div class="wrapper" id="card-deck">
            <div class="card" data-type="1"><h2>What information should you NEVER use in a password?</h2></div>
            <div id="answerSix" class="card"  data-type="6"><h2>1 log in</h2></div>
            <div id="cardThree" class="card"  data-type="3"><h2>When should you ALWAYS change your password?</h2></div>
            <div id="anserFive" class="card"  data-type="5"><h2>suspicious activity</h2></div>
            <div id="cardTwo" class="card"  data-type="2"><h2>Who is it okay to tell your password to?</h2></div>
            <div id="answerFour" class="card" data-type="4"><h2>16</h2></div>
            <div id="answerThree" class="card" data-type="3"><h2>After a data breach</h2></div>
            <div id="answerTwo" class="card" data-type="2"><h2>No one</h2></div>
            <div id="CardSix" class="card" data-type="6"><h2>For how many log ins is it okay to use the same password?</h2></div>
            <div id="cardFour" class="card" data-type="4"><h2>How many characters should you AT LEAST use in a password?</h2></div>
            <div class="card" data-card="firstSet" data-type="1"><h2>Name and Birthday</h2></div>
            <div id="cardFive" class="card" data-type="5"><h2>What should you regularly look for in your accounts?</h2></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="facts">
        <h2>DID YOU KNOW?</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="tcontainer"><div class="ticker-wrap"><div class="ticker-move">
        <div class="ticker-item">There is a hacker attack every 39 seconds.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">90% of passwords can be cracked in less than 6 hours.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">80% of hacking related breaches are linked to insufficient passwords.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">59% use their name or birthday in their password.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">6.850.000 passwords are getting hacked each day.</div>
      </div></div></div>

    <div class="pause">
        <p>Hold your mouse over to pause</p>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript/javascript.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anna100d/pen/wvgQLdW

Answer (score 0):

Problems with code can be much easier to understand and solve if they can be simplified first. Here is **a stripped-down version of your game** that makes it easy to focus on the logic of the click event listener.  (Opening a card in this version merely changes its color.)

In the listener, when the **first card** is clicked, we want to open it and remember it for later.

When the **second card** is clicked, we open it and compare it to the first card, then we must forget the first card. (If they match, the score changes; if not, we close both cards.)

---

**Edit:**
If the two cards don't match, both cards get closed. To let the user see the selected cards while they're both open, you can put the code that closes the cards into a function and pass that function to JavaScript's built-in [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#settimeout) function.

I updated the snippet to include this behavior (using a couple of additional tricks while I was at it: the "rest" syntax, a "fat arrow" function, and a "closure" -- Search for the respective pages on MDN if you want to learn more about these features.)

```js
// Declares global variables
let score = 0, cardToMatch = null;
    
// Calls `flipCard` on any click
window.addEventListener("click", flipCard);


// Defines the click listener
function flipCard(event){

  // Identifies the card where the click happened
  const card = event.target.closest(".card");

  // Ignores irrelevant/invalid clicks
  if(!card || card.classList.contains("open")){
    return;
  }

  // A valid click always opens the card
  card.classList.add("open");

  // If this is the 1st card of 2, remember it
  if(!cardToMatch){
    cardToMatch = card;
  }
  // If it's the 2nd card, compare types
  else{

    // If they match...
    if(card.dataset.type == cardToMatch.dataset.type){

      // ...Increment score and show it in the DOM
      updateScoreDisplay(++score);
    }

    // If they don't...
    else{
      // ...Flip both cards back over
      resetCardsAfterDelay(cardToMatch, card);
    }
    // Either way, next click will be the 1st of 2
    cardToMatch = null;
  }
}

function updateScoreDisplay(newScore){
  // Syncs the user-displayed value w/ score
  const element = document.querySelector(".score span");
  element.textContent = newScore;
}

function resetCardsAfterDelay(...listOfCards){
  //Takes any number of cards via "rest parameter syntax"
  // Uses `setTimeout` to call inner `resetAll` func after delay

  // Passes our `resetAll` func to `setTimeout` with a delay in milliseconds
  const DELAY = 1200;
  setTimeout(resetAll, DELAY);

  // Inner func (a "closure") knows about `listOfCards`
  function resetAll(){
    // In a loop, applies a "fat arrow" func to each card
    listOfCards.forEach(
      (card) => card.classList.remove("open")
    )
  }
};
```

```css
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.header{ margin: 0.3rem; font-size: 1.1rem; }
.score{ margin: 0.3em; font-weight: bold; }
.card{
  width: 14em; margin: 0.3em; padding: 0.1em 0.3em;
  border-radius: 0.5em; border: 1px solid grey;
}
.open{ background-color: lightskyblue; }
```

```html
<h1 class="header">The Password Game</h1>

<div class="score">Score: <span>0</span> </div>

<hr/>

<div class="card" data-type="1"> Never use..? (1) </div>
<div class="card" data-type="1"> Name and Birthday (1) </div>
<div class="card" data-type="2"> Tell password to..? (2) </div>
<div class="card" data-type="2"> No one (2) </div>
<div class="card" data-type="3"> Always change PW..? (3) </div>
<div class="card" data-type="3"> After a data breach (3) </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i have been struggeling for 2 weeks now

Comment: When i try to open the second card, the js compares the second card to the first card before it opens, so i don't event get to see the second card if it doesn't match the first one. do i need to add a delay?

Comment: Exactly. If you haven't already implemented a `setTimeout` to handle this, see the updated answer.